# how do I get Active Admin custom sorting to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm trying to use the Custom Sorting feature described in https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.md#custom-sorting, but can't seem to get it to work with a very simple case. The repo for my code is here: https://github.com/newton10471/active_admin_custom_sorting. For what it's worth, I'm using older versions of Rails (4.2.5), and Active Admin (1.1.0).

In my repo mentioned above, my AdminUser model looks like this:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :gold_stars
end
```

and my GoldStar model looks like this:

```
class GoldStar < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :admin_user_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :admin_user
end
```

I want to be able to sort on the 'Gold Stars' column, which is a count of the number of Gold Stars each AdminUser has earned.

My attempt to use custom sorting looks like this, in app/admin/admin_user.rb:

```
order_by(:gold_stars) do |order_clause|
  ['COUNT(gold_stars.id)', order_clause.to_sql].join(' ')
end

index do
  column :gold_stars, sortable: true do |admin_user|
    admin_user.gold_stars.count
  end
end
```

But the column isn't enabled as sortable unless I include sortable: true, which makes me think that either I'm doing something wrong or something is not working properly. The setup above doesn't seem to make it sort things any differently than the default case. Looking at the Rails log, it doesn't look like the SQL query is modified, although params[:order] gets populated with what looks like a Proc, along the lines of "Proc:0x00007fb3c40c8080@/Users/user/active_admin_custom_sorting/app/admin/admin_user.rb:12_desc"